# Select of 2 related tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have these 2 tables:

**Table Users:**

```
id | name
---------
1  | Joe
2  | Sara
3  | Michael
```

**Table Sales:**

```
id |  product  | user_id
------------------------
1  |    Car    | 2
2  |   Truck   | 3
3  | motorcycle| 1
4  |    Car    | 2
5  |   Truck   | 1
6  |    Car    | 3
7  |    Car    | 2
8  |   Truck   | 3
9  |    Car    | 2
10 |    Car    | 3
```

**I want the following:**

```
User Name  | Car | Truck | Motorcycle
Joe        |  0  |   1   |     1
Sara       |  4  |   0   |     0
Michael    |  2  |   2   |     0
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--For a small number of products this works,

```
Select username
, Sum(case when product = 'Car' then 1 else 0 End) Cars
, Sum(case when product = 'Truck' then 1 else 0 End) Truck
, Sum(case when product = 'motorcycle' then 1 else 0 End) motorcycle
From Sales s join users u on s.userid = u.userid
group by username
```

Comment: You can remove the second query MySQL doesnt support the pivot function..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Users.name,
SUM(Case 
   WHEN product='Car' then 1
   ELSE 0
) AS Car,
SUM(Case 
   WHEN product='Truck' then 1
   ELSE 0
) AS Truck   ,
SUM(Case 
   WHEN product='Motorcycle' then 1
   ELSE 0
) AS Motorcycle,
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN Sales ON Users.id = Sales.user_id
GROUP BY Users.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    name as UserName ,  
    SUM(product= 'Car')AS Car,
    SUM(product= 'Truck')AS Truck,
    SUM(product= 'motorcycle') AS motorcycle
FROM Users join Sales
on Users.id = Sales.user_id
GROUP BY name
```

hope it helps but still this is a standard solution you should check pivot Tables.